# pywinauto Installing an application on windows

Tags: pywinauto

I am currently working on the automation of the installation of an app,but seems like I am stuck.I could open the app but when I try to click on the install button nothing happens.I referred to the notepad example and tried to make it work. Here is what I have done till now.Please someone help:

```
app = pywinauto.Application().Start(r'b.exe')
Wizard = app['Bluebeam Revu 2018.1']
Wizard['&Install'].Click()
```

I also tried Wizard.Install.Click and Wizard.Button0.Click(),Where Button0 is the name of the install button.

Comment: Can you try some pause before `.Click()`? Like `time.sleep(2)`.

Comment: I tried that also but it doesn't work,I am new to this .I also tried to get the handle.hand=pywinauto.findwindows.find_window(best_match="Bluebeam Revu 2018.1")
    window = pwa_app.window_(handle=hand)
    window.Click()
    ctrl=window['&Install']
    ctrl.ClickInput()

Comment: .click_input() should work instead of .click(). Method .click() sends window message WM_LBUTTONCLICK, while .click_input() operates with real mouse cursor.

Comment: I have been trying to do that but it still doesn't work. Is there something I am missing? could you look into this If I give you the link for the download? That would be a huge help.I tried this with notepad and one more application and it worked.

Comment: I can take a short look if it's publicly available. Please post the link.

Comment: https://www.bluebeam.com/trials/ ... dowload any one ..problem is just clicking the install button.That is it..so that wouldn't require any registration info just the "install button click"

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue when I tried to automate installation of Adobe Acrobat Reader DC  using pywinauto. click or click_input methods didn't work as expected. But when I ran my script as an administrator the problem got resolved. So, you should have logged in as an administrator or at least run your script as an administrator.